# Install express-generator without global attribute

Tags: node.js, express, express-generator

I am working on a VPS through Dreamhost and they do not allow the use of `sudo` so I can not install `express-generator` globally. I really like all the files that express initiates when calling the `express` command. Is there a way to install `express-generator` without the global attribute or a way to get all the files that the command `express` initializes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember when you `npm install x` then there's always the option of running whatever it installed via `node_modules/x/bin/x` if that's the name of the shell command it installs.

Comment: you can then add `node_modules/x/bin/x` to your path to use it as if it had been installed globally

Comment: Can you explain in more detail about how I can achieve this? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Just have a look in the installed directory, you'll see the script is sitting there, executable: `node_modules/express-generator/bin/express` in your case.